# Pygame failing. Badly

Tags: python, pygame

I've been trying to learn pygame from [this site](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php), and it keeps failing.

I'm almost certain it's supposed to be Python 3. 
Here's the code that's failing (straight from the site):

```
import pygame
# COLORS
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
# Screen dimensions
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
# The Player. Without a player, what is a game?
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super.__init__()
        # Set height, width
        self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 15])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)

        # Make our top-left corner the passed-in location.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

        # Set speed vector
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
        self.walls = None

        def changespeed(self, x, y):
            # WHAT DO YOU THINK THIS DOES YOU TWAT?
            # keff keff. It changes the player's speed.
            self.change_x += x
            self.change_y += y

        def update(self):
            # Update player position.
            # Move left/right
            self.rect.x += self.change_x

            # Did we run into a wall?
            block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls,   False)
            for block in block_hit_list:
                # Keep that player OUT!
                if self.change_y > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
                else:
                    self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom
            # Same thing for up and down, now we only have one variable to mess with
            self.rect.y += self.change_y

            # NOW did we run into a wall?
            block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)
            for block in block_hit_list:
                # Please leave the premises.
                if self.change_y > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
                else:
                    self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom


class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # Defines a wall. I mean what else can this do?
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        # Construction.
        super().__init__()
        # Make it blue, and not invisible
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(BLUE)
        # Make the top left corner where we "center" the thing
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x
    # That was easy. Most of the work is done by the player and not the walls.


# Initialize pygame
pygame.init()
# Create the pygame window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT])
# This line is fairly self explanatory...
pygame.display.set_caption('1-2 WALLS')
# Make a list of all the sprites, a census.
all_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
# Now we build our walls.
wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
# Each wall follows a format to be created
# You can copy-paste this over and over till you're happy
# Define a wall @ x, y, x2, y2
wall = Wall(0, 0, 10, 600)
# Put it in the appropriate lists
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)
#blank line here
wall = Wall(10, 0, 790, 10)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(10, 200, 100, 10)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

# Spawn a player at x 50 y 50.
player = Player(50, 50)
player.walls = wall_list

all_sprite_list.add(player)
# Start the clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

done = False

while not done:
    # ask pygame what's happening so we can deal with it
    for event in pygame.event.get():
    # Did they quit the game?
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0, 3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0, -3)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0, 3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0, -3)

    # Update our census
    all_sprite_list.update()

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    all_sprite_list.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

When I run it, I get an error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 16, in __init__

    super.__init__()

TypeError: descriptor '__init__' of 'super' object needs an argument
```

Comment: try 

pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

Comment: Instead of `super.__init__(self)`? Will do.

Comment: ... That fixes the errors with making the player. Now I have a screwy pygame setup to fix... (probably just the way I have things set up, `if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` doesn't sound like it's this code)

Comment: @magi093 Read @DanielRoseman's answer, there was absolutely no need to use `pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)`, you should've just added parenthesis.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Now I just feel stupid. Thanks. Now to work on the other error.

Comment: @magi093 Thank Daniel.

Comment: My stupidity seems to be growing, the other issue was also due to parentheses (having them in the wrong place)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should notice that you are calling `super` differently in Wall and Player. The way you are doing it in Wall is correct:

```
super().__init__()
```

whereas in Player you are missing the parentheses after `super`.

Comment: You fixed the player! Sitll got a few bugs, but TBH my pygame setup is probably the cause and not the code. Have a vote and accepted answer.